# How to focus textbox and send ENTER key using child handle?

Tags: c#

How to focus and send 'ENTER' key to child control's textbox? code:

```
 //Get textbox child handle
 IntPtr TextboxChild = FindWindow("Edit", "mulatetwindow");
 //SetFocus to textbox
 int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
 int EN_SETFOCUS = 0x0100;
 SendMessage(TextboxChild, WM_COMMAND, EN_SETFOCUS, null);
 //Send ENTER key
 int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
 int VK_RETURN = 0x0D;
 int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
 SendMessage(TextboxChild, WM_KEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, null);
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
 SendMessage(TextboxChild, WM_KEYUP, VK_RETURN, null);
```

I tried the code in above, it didn't work.

[spy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chugp.png)

[spy2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVLf1.png)

Comment: Please be more specific than "does not work". Do you get a valid window handle? If not, is the owning process running elevated?

Comment: Window handle and child handle is working but doesnt work SendMessage function. I coded set text instead of key. worked. i want to focus other textbox and send 'ENTER' key.

Comment: Topic updated. Please review again

Comment: `EN_` seem to be notifications sent _by_ the Edit control which won't change its state. If you want to send a message _to_ the control, you have to use the `EM` messages, in fact, I thought `EM_TAKEFOCUS` may help you here but it states to work only for single-line edit controls you apparently don't have. Does `WM_SETFOCUS` work for other processes?

Comment: Can you please show the sample code?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any. I only know SetFocus works for own processes, so posting the "corresponding" message to other processes was just an idea. :(